# How to plot multiple plots on same row?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am using the classic [kaggle house price dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction/data). I want to plot each of the feature columns (`bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `sqft_living` etc.) against the `price` target to check for any correlation, but I want to have say 3 or 4 plots on each row to make the plot more compact.

What I have done so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns;
sns.set_context('poster')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

df = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
cols = [i for i in list(df.columns) if i not in ['id','price']]
for col in cols:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    df.plot(kind='scatter', x=col, y='price', ax=ax, s=10, alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

So, I am using the inbuilt pandas plotting functionality, *but this plots each figure on a new line.*

What I would like to have is something like the [pandas scatter matrix plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/visualization.html#visualization-scatter-matrix) where multiple (in this case 4) plots appear on one line. (I don't need to plot the distribution along the diagonal as shown below).

[image]

How can I have multiple plots in one row using the pandas `scatter_matrix` functionality or some other python plotting functionality?

Nice to haves:

1. Labeled axes
2. Correlation between each feature and `price` displayed on each plot

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new subplot every iteration. Instead, create one subplot with multiple columns and put each plot on its own axis with the `ax` parameter to `pd.plot()`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(cols), figsize=(12,8), squeeze=False)

for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    df.plot(kind='scatter', x=col, y='price', ax=axes[0, i], s=10, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: this produces an error `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`; something is wrong with the `ax` argument

Comment: Yes, I put in a wrong number. Does it work now? I just edited my answer

Comment: @Peter Not working for me, only the latest plot canvas is being "filled"